# Editable Bootstrap Table "Jumping"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a table with Bootstrap classes editable by double clicking on a cell. However the cell width automatically grows and makes other columns "jump" which can be annoying.

Here is a rough example that demonstrates my problem:

```
var tbl = $("#tbl");

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     var row = $("<tr/>"),
         cols = [ $("<td/>"), $("<td/>") ],
         input = $("<input/>", {
             type: "text",
             class: "form-control",
         });

    cols[0].text(i);
    cols[1].text(i * 2);

    cols[0].on("dblclick", function() {
        var cell = $(this);

        input.val(cell.text());
        cell.html(input);
    });

    row.append(cols[0]);
    row.append(cols[1]);
    tbl.append(row);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fvx/1/)

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here `CSS` does the trick, add this css:

```
th{
    width:200px;
}
```

and, if requires this too:

```
tr
{
    height:45px;
}
```

basically we are fixing `Height` (and `Width`) of the `Table Cell`.

You can also remove that `Blue Color Selection` on Double Click by CSS,

See Fiddle: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/Jkp7Z/3/)